# Can I use the WP7 Panorama control outside of WP7?

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I need a WPF control that acts like the Panorama control for Windows Phone 7, but I need it for a desktop application.

It will contain a series of panels (or Panorama Items) that the application will be able to slide through horizontally programmatically.

Also, the content inside the panels not currently displayed on the screen will need to be "lazy loaded". In other words, they should be referenced but not loaded or rendered.

Can I somehow adapt the WP7 Panorama control to do this? Or will I have to develop a custom control from scratch to behave similarly to it?

Thank you!

EDIT:
I could probably use a VirtualizingPanel to implement the lazyload behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

[MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/MahApps.Metro/) while still not super mature does allow for the wp7 Panorama control. [Demo of how to use a panorama here](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MetroDemo/PanoramaDemo.xaml). I've played with it a little and while its not the most customizable thing out there it gets the job done. Pretty sweet. Also Sacha Barber (Codeproject Demigod) wrote up [an article on making your own.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/370650/Simple-Metro-Style-Panorama-Control-For-WPF) Of which I haven't looked at yet but, the guy usually does awesome work. So I'd check that one out as well.

Answer (score 1):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/arielbh/archive/2010/10/21/porting-windows-phone-7-s-panorama-control-to-silverlight-4.aspx gives some clues about how do to this.

It suggests using http://phone.codeplex.com/ as your base and then you can use http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=4b281bde-9b01-4890-b3d4-b3b45ca2c2e4 (Microsoft Surface Manipulations and Inertia Sample for Microsoft Silverlight) to run convert get it to respond to touch.

Answer (score 0):

Seems none exist as far as I can see so far.

[This blog](http://mareinsula.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/step-1-to-create-wpf-panorama-control/) has started an attempt at making it, so you could work from there to make your own. Be sure to also check out [this page](http://mareinsula.wordpress.com/2011/06/10/wpf-panoramaitem/) which details the creation of an individual panorama item too.